# Getting JSON with functions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the root of my `.js` file I declare:

```
var Doe = {
            "foo": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
            "bar": "ABCDEFG",
            "baz": [52, 97],
            "testfunc": function(){alert('json function');}
           }
```

And in my HTML:

```
<a id="lele" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Doe.testfunc()">Doe</a>
```

And when I click it it works, so I know it's possible to put functions in JSON objets.

Now, in the root of the `.js` I declare:

```
$.getJSON("~/rule/2", function(data) {
    alert("2: " + data.foo);
    data.testfunc();
});
```

And the server is returning this for that url:

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 context.Response.Output.Write(@"{
                     ""foo"": ""The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."",
                     ""bar"": ""ABCDEFG"",
                     ""baz"": [52, 97],
                     ""testfunc"": function(){alert('json function');}  
                                 }");
  context.Response.Flush();
```

But nothing happens :( Aparently because if there is an error, .getJSON will fail silently. But, if I remove the lines regarding of the function:

```
$.getJSON("~/rule/2", function(data) {
    alert("2: " + data.foo);
});
```

and

```
 context.Response.Output.Write(@"{
                     ""foo"": ""The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."",
                     ""bar"": ""ABCDEFG"",
                     ""baz"": [52, 97]}");
```

Then it works, an alert pop up with the content of the "foo" property.

What is the problem with the function? :( In the moment that I put a function in the JSON object, jQuery fails.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't have a JSON object.**

You have an *object literal*. Functions **cannot** be values of a JSON string.

JSON is only a **subset** of the object literal syntax. Possible values are:

[image: values]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/value.gif))</sub>

Read more on [json.org](https://json.org/)

This is JavaScript object:

```
var foo = {bar: 42}
```

and this is a JSON string:

```
var foo = '{"bar": 42}';
```

See also [JavaScript, JSON objects and object literal notation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110415114151/http://thoughts.felix-kling.de:80/post/2712535102/javascript-json-objects-and-object-literal-notation).

**Update:** In order to return and execute JavaScript, you can do the following:

You can return plain JavaScript e.g.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
context.Response.Output.Write(@"
 function testfunc(){
     alert('json function')
 };
 testfunc();
");
```

and use [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType: 'script'`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "~/rule/2",
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rCgtb/)

You can also define JavaScript objects with functions like so:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
context.Response.Output.Write(@"
     var obj = {
         bar: function(){alert(42);}
     }
     yourHandler(obj);
");
```

You just need to have a global function called `yourHandler` (and of course still call `ajax` with `dataType: script`).

This is probably what comes closest to what you want. The difference is, that you don't return JSON, but JavaScript, and you don't process the object in the `success` callback, but in another function, which has to be called from within the JS you sent.

See another [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rCgtb/2/)

Comment: d'oh! how could i do that then? I mean, download and execute custom JS code form the server? Thanks.

Comment: Answers with graphics deserve a +1 (and for the rest of the content too, of course). :o)

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible to put functions in JSON objects. It's possible to put functions in JavaScript objects though, which is what you've demonstrated in the first snippet.

Comment: d'oh! how could i do that then? I mean, download and execute custom JS code form the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could place just string representation the function body in your JSON that you're sending, then give that data to the `Function` constructor.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m8PQY/1/

```
var myJSON = '{"func":"{alert(\'json function\');}"}';

var obj = $.parseJSON( myJSON );

var myFunc = new Function( obj.func );

myFunc();
```

Obviously you would only want to do this if you are the author of the code you're sending.